# Discord Python Bot unable to set prefix

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Okay so I am designing a Discord bot in Python, am pretty new though. I was trying to get it to join a voice channel so I did some research and came up with the following, I cut out the irrelevant part of the bot so this is just the part with the voice connection. It says: undefined name "commands" over the line that should set the prefix:

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Eingeloggt als {0.user}".format(client))

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: You have `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` and then you write `@bot.command()`. Try using `@client.command()` instead since that's your variable for the commands or change the client variable to bot

Comment: @PhoenixDoom yeah, I realised that as well, I changed it and there are no errors left but it still won't work.

Comment: Does the bot have permission to send messages?

Comment: @PhoenixDoom yes it does, the other functions which I did not show in the code snippet work as expected.

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event? Sometimes commands stop working because of this.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `from discord.ext import commands`

```py
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Eingeloggt als {0.user}".format(client))

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: okay thanks, I do not get any error lines now anymore. However it won't work, I tried simple commands such as 
```
@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)
```
if I send !foo abc nothing gets back, nothing in the terminal nor in discord

Comment: Thats a separate question @Apster137. Better to ask a new one